# Setting up and running Python scripts on my shared hosting plan

Tags: python

I have a shared hosting plan with a cheap hosting provider. Up until now I was able to survive with just PHP scripts and FTP access. I am interested in learning how to do things with Python however.

My question is, how do I connect to the server and install or run Python scripts? Can I do everything via FTP or do I need access to a console via telnet?

Comment: The specific host provided is mentioned in the previous edit if that helps answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should have to do is upload your .py scripts via FTP, just like you would with .php, .css, .js etc. scripts.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add that I have a MySQL database too. I skimmed a few references, and they seemed to imply that Python cannot communicate with the database without installing other libraries. How do I test if this is the case? And will I need a terminal to install those libraries?

Comment: I am not sure how python talks to mysql, but I imagine that if python is installed all the libraries will be there.  You ought to take this up with your hosting company as they will be the people installing the libraries if they aren't there...not you.

Comment: They aren't going to do anything unless I provide specific details. I'll start new questions to find out those details, however.

Comment: Find a new host :P

Comment: I talked to my host via email, and he said they don't allow "mysql-python modules" on shared hosting plans. I wish there were an easy way to check hosting providers for stuff like this before you subscribe.